# How to create a Haskell Tree Structure to display like c# inherited class structure.(if I understand correct)

Tags: haskell, types, tree

I'm familiar with C# related programming languages, but I have a Haskell question.

I have a string, which is a list of words. I need to put it in a tree structure, and display out. For example, need to display something like this:

The tree should look like this: 1st layer one String, 2nd layer is 3 list of strings, grouped from the 1st layer string, 3rd layer is 3 groups category names as Enum.

```
"the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy black dog"
("the", "quick", "jumped", "over", "the", "lazy"), ("brown", "black"), ("fox", "dog")
"Other Words", "Colour", "Animal"
```

So, I can understand if in c#, these can be in a hierarchical class, and `ToString` to display.

I'm new with Haskell. I wrote the functions to parse the string to the final line of categories, but I can not understand how to put the data in the Tree structure and display?

Comment: Could you explain what your tree is? I don't understand from your question what sort of tree structure you mean to create?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I updated the post with tree details.

Comment: I am also a bit confused about what kind of tree structure you need. Could you post some C# code that does what you need?

Comment: Why not have second layer containing "Other Words", "Colour", "Animal" and the bottom layer containing the individual words?

Answer (score 3):

Data types are cheap in Haskell.  Let's define some to prove it!

```
data Layer1 = L1 String [Layer2]
```

This defines a data type named `Layer1` that has a constructor named `L1`.  This constructor holds two fields: a `String` that holds the name of this node, and a list of children of some as-yet-unspecified type `Layer2`.

Let's define the second type:

```
data Layer2 = L2 String [String]
```

This type is just like the previous one, except that its children are strings.

But what if we wanted to keep going for as many layers as we want?  Well, fortunately, Haskell accepts recursively defined data structures.  If we generalize our first type, it can store itself as children:

```
data Layer1 = Layer1 String [Layer1]
```

In other words, every `Layer1` holds a string and a list of children that are even more `Layer1`s.  In fact, this is basically the definition of a tree:

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, for my understanding, once a variable is set, the value of it can not be changed. So, when I analyse this string, it has to create layer one at a time, the question is how to modify the value after the 1st layer created? Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @WinterWinter You create a new tree.  Fortunately this is not as bad as it sounds since if you reuse old parts of the original tree then they will not be recomputed.